# Toggle Hamburger Dropdown: How to call ancestor with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble toggling the hamburger drop-down menu. Basically I have the hamburger icon in a container, but the navigation list is in a great grandparent div, and I don't know how to toggle the display for the navigation list from inside a lower ancestor div using JQuery.

**Edit:** Forgot to specify that I want to display the navigation list with the container's myFunction(this) if possible

```
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header_content">
      <div class="header_icon">
        <span class="toggle">
            <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
                <div class="bar1"></div>
                <div class="bar2"></div>
                <div class="bar3"></div>
            </div>
        </span>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jsd6gg/qsvw8c1v/5/)

Comment: i cant see hamburger on your fiddle

Comment: It's in the output section inside the black header. You might need to make the screen smaller since the list switches from a nav bar to a hambuger at 850px

Comment: yeah, right. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could give the Ancestor element an id
like `<ul id='menu'></ul>`
And then use jQuery like `$('#menu')` to access this element via its ID and do whatever you like with it.

This works with every element in the DOM as long as the ID is unique, which it should be.

Edit (Link to jQuery Selector Docs):
[jQuery-Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: Would I be able to call #menu from the container's onclick function? I know I can do that for the header, but I want it to activate when I click on the hamburger.

Comment: The ID should be Unique in the whole Document and wherever you can call jQuery from you should be able to access every element by its ID

Comment: You should note that the '#' sign is not part of the ID but tells jQuery that you are searching for an Element by ID

Comment: I tried   `  function myFunction(x) {
   x.classList.toggle("change");
           $('menu').toggle();
  }
but it didn't work`

Comment: you are missing the '#' before menu.
and you must set the id attribute on the element